# Passing an argument to an exe through matlab

Tags: c, matlab, parameter-passing, exe, command-line-arguments

I have a c program exe that I’m running through matlab using the system command.
The c program has a get_char in it and I’m trying to pass an argument through matlab to the console of the exe automatically (through the matlab code and not by typing the char in the console).
All the solutions I found seem to pass an argument to the main function but my code doesn’t allow it because the main function receives void.
I know this method is possible through python but I haven’t found a matlab solution.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks!

I tried putting the argument in the system command which seem to result in passing the argument to a function (which in my c program doesn’t expect input)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe input to your program in your `system` command. This works fine if you have only a single line of input to send to your program. If you have multiple lines, you might need to put them into a file and then use `<` redirection instead. Something like this:

```matlab
[s,w] = system(sprintf('echo "input goes here" | program_goes_here'));
```